# redirect Login problems

Tags: redirect, login

I use this code in my funtions to redirect all the people without login to my login page, but the link "lost my password" don´t work and continue redirect to login page.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

José Vieira

```
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_restrict_guest_access' );
function cyb_restrict_guest_access() {
    global $wp;
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! cyb_is_login_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url( site_url( $wp->request ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}

function cyb_is_login_page() {
    return in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('wp-login.php'));
}
```

Comment: what is your lost my password code related? what is the link? how you setup?